# Only one of two listeners get called when pressing buttons

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons in my activity and two `OnClickListener`s corresponding to them.

```
createGroupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create_group_in_login);
createGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new CreateGroupLoadingListener());

editProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_edit_profile);
editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new ProfileEditListener());

private class ProfileEditListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                EditProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private class CreateGroupLoadingListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                CreateGroupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Whenever I click either button, only one listener gets run. For example, in one session, whether I click the create group button or edit profile button, only `EditProfileActivity` runs. Why am I getting this behaviour?

Comment: Can you post the xml also?

Comment: If you click on `1` button, only `1` listener will run. What is the problem? Do you mean to say, no matter which button you click, always the same listener runs?

Comment: Try deleting and recreating the R.java file

Comment: May be your `CreateGroupActivity` is messed up, its being launched but it finishes itself and starts `EditProfileActivity`.

Comment: this code looks fine, need to see the bindings for the buttons - possible both buttons are bound to the `R.id.button_edit_profile`

Comment: have you checked your createGroupActivity

Comment: You could also try to clean project and build again, sometimes the xml gets wrongly compiled along the java code.

Comment: It seems everything ok, can you clean your project and run again..

Comment: The problem may lie in R.java. Deleting it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this out n let me know whats the o/p

**Comment the listener for your editprofile**

```
createGroupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create_group_in_login);
createGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new CreateGroupLoadingListener());

editProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_edit_profile);
//editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new ProfileEditListener());
/*
private class ProfileEditListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                EditProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
*/
private class CreateGroupLoadingListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                CreateGroupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```